# Is it possible to use the Realm Kotlin Multiplatform SDK with only IntelliJ (not Android Studio)?

Tags: gradle, realm, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

In my Kotlin Multiplatform app I use IntelliJ for the shared libraries rather than Android Studio. So far that approach has worked fine but when I looked at using the Realm Kotlin Multiplatform SDK - to my surprise - the documentation states that it requires Android Studio.

I thought I would give it a try anyway but I didn't have any success. Is this actually possible?

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/install/kotlin-multiplatform/

---

### Initially I added

```
plugins {
    id("io.realm.kotlin")
}
```

and

```
val commonMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt")
        implementation("io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.0.0")
    }
}
```

**but not this** since I don't have an Android Studio style project level build.gradle. Since I'm not using a mono repo I don't have two separate build.gradle files. The one I have is at the project level but has the contents of what the app level build.gradle would look like.

```
classpath("io.realm.kotlin:gradle-plugin:1.0.0") // did not add this
```

---

### At this point the project would not complete a gradle sync.

I have a settings.gradle file with

```
if (requested.id.namespace == "com.android" || requested.id.name == "kotlin-android-extensions") {
    useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3")
}
```

so I tried

```
if (requested.id.namespace == "io.realm" || requested.id.name == "kotlin-android-extensions") {
    useModule("io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.0.0")
}
```

thinking maybe that could substitute for not using `classpath("io.realm.kotlin:gradle-plugin:1.0.0")` anywhere but it didn't help.

---

### I was able to get the Gradle sync to complete successfully

by using `id("io.realm.kotlin") version "1.0.0"` in the plugin block instead of just `id("io.realm.kotlin")` as specified in the documentation.

---

### However it won't compile when I try to publish to mavel local

I get this sort of error. I say this sort of error because if I run the publish to maven local task again the target will be different; it cycles through them each time for some reason. So I don't literally get the same error each time I run the task.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileKotlinIosArm64'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':iosArm64CompileKlibraries'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt.
     Required by:
         project :
         project : > io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.0.0 > io.realm.kotlin:library-sync-iosarm64:1.0.0
         project : > io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.0.0 > io.realm.kotlin:library-sync-iosarm64:1.0.0 > io.realm.kotlin:library-base:1.0.0 > io.realm.kotlin:library-base-iosarm64:1.0.0
         ...
```

I tried adding the coroutines dependency to each target specifically but that didn't help either.

Also, if I comment out the realm plugin and dependency but just leave the coroutines dependency there it publishes to maven local without any issues.

---

I asked on the Kotlin slack group in the realm channel and it was suggested that it "should" work so wondering if anyone else knows the trick or if you know if it's NOT possible.

Thanks.

---

### Edit

I created a test library and was able to get it to compile. I was also able to reproduce the issue by adding ktor libraries which seem to conflict with `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt")`. I still wasn't able to find a solution though.

It says to use `strictly` here but not sure how to make ktor use that version https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines.

Also, even without ktor it still doesn't compile if I add iosSimulatorArm64 as a target. In that case I get this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileKotlinIosSimulatorArm64'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':iosSimulatorArm64CompileKlibraries'.
   > Could not resolve io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.0.1.
```

---

### Edit 2

I thought what the heck I'll try to create a multiplatform library with Android Studio (chipmonk) just to see if that works. Nope. Even worse. Without doing anything except create the project from the wizard I get these sorts of errors all over the place in the build files with no clear indication of what's causing it:

```
Cannot access 'java.lang.Comparable' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

I think I'm gonna have to either find a different way to store and sync local data or put KMP on hold for now until things are a bit more stable and just do full native and write all the code multiple times. I seem to be pretty much out of options for solving this.